# force quit download from App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

How can I force quit download from App Store? I wanted to download OS X El Capitan for virtual machine usage (I don't have Install El Capitan.app in Applications for some reason), but my download is stuck:

Looks like this:

[image]

I can't reinitiate download, because I am already "downloading". How can I force quit download so that I can start fresh? Maybe the question should be, which activity should I cancel in Activity Monitor?

Comment: When this happens on my iPhone I just restart and it goes away.  Have you tried restarting your Mac?

Comment: yes, I already did.

Comment: Try going to the App Store and check for unfinished downloads.  Do this under `Store --> Check for unfinished downloads`.  You might be able to delete or restart it from there.

Comment: I restarted it again, but this time I didn't click Resume in Purchased tab of App store, but went on and Download it again from App Store search results. The download started. Not sure why.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer, and you can accept, for others who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the **App Store** and resume any unfinished downloads.

To do that, open the **App Store** and in the menu go to `Store --> Check for unfinished downloads`.  Enter your login credentials.  You can see any downloads that didn't complete.  From there you can restart or delete it.

[image]